# Mobile Service caching

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

Im calling a custom API azure mobile service. The response in given by a dynamic schema.
Ive changed the schema, but it seems like azure has cached the old one. If i change to a entity type as return type , all is ok. But the moment I change back to a dynamic schema azure uses the old schema. Any ideas ?

Just for reference, my dynamic schema looks like this

```
[DataContract]
public class HigscoreItem
{
public HigscoreItem(Int32 aq, Int32 sec, string userId, Int32 rank, bool npb, Int32     distance)
{
            AnsweredQuestions = aq;
            Seconds = sec;
            UserId = userId;
            Rank = rank;
            NewPersonalBest = npb? 1 : 0;
            DistanceLeft = distance;
        }
        [DataMember(Name = "answeredquestions")]
        public Int32 AnsweredQuestions;
        [DataMember(Name = "seconds")]
        public Int32 Seconds;
        [DataMember(Name = "userid")]
        public string UserId;
        [DataMember(Name = "rank")]
        public Int32 Rank;
        [DataMember(Name = "distanceleft")]
        public Int32 DistanceLeft;
        [DataMember(Name = "newpersonalbest")]
        public Int32 NewPersonalBest;
    }
```

}

Comment: MS documentation recommends disabling dynamic schema [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193175.aspx) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193175.aspx Where is this done. Maybe Ive misunderstood what a dynamic schema is ??

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience :/ Values of int (0) is not put in the JSON packet... Thats what tricked me :P. But still wondering about that MS documentation recommending disabling dynamic schema ??

Answer (score 0):

As Knutdag noted in the comments above, the integer zero is not serialized, so the object going to the database looks different, and the database will change its schema accordingly if dynamic schema is on.

You should turn Dynamic Schema off when going to production so that you don't end up with a loss of data, either due to a bug in a new version (like an int 0) or even a malicious insert. The idea is that once your app is live, you have decided on your schema, and you shouldn't need to change it without being explicit. Dynamic schema is meant as an initial development tool, and it gives you the flexibility of having the system work end-to-end while you are still figuring out what the client data models look like. Once you're in production, you have real data, and you want to manage schema changes manually to make sure things go smoothly